# Find Every Instance of "<br />" in a page and remove it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working within a template using the Cargo Collective platform and it adds unecessary `<br />` tags inside the `body` of my document.

How can I write a line or two of jQuery to search for every `<br />` tag on my page and remove them, or replace them with nothing?

Comment: I think you should have a look at [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the selector `br` and `.remove()`, like so.

```
$('br').remove();
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b8VA/)**

Answer (score 11):

No doubt, Austins answer is perfect, but if you want, you can also use `display: none;`

```
br {
   display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqnc/)

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't think of this. Especially because I already used display:none to take out other elements on the page lol

Comment: +1. Would always prefer CSS over JS as you never know some people might keep JS disabled

Comment: @asprin Thanks ;) and yes, I don't rely on JS if we can accomplish things with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Additionally ,for in a specific div or element

```
#some_element br {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: :)  @JanDvorak why not take it for this as a followers ??

Comment: This is what I ended up using -- it's the most specific. This way I can use `br` tags in other parts of the page.